# ASP.NET Profiles - Add a profile to an existing user

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, asp.net-membership, profiles

How do you add a profile entry (consisting of a guid, two strings, and an integer) to an existing user in the default SQL profile and membership providers?  I can do this either via a sql query or C# code.

I need to add a bunch of these profiles to already existing users.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use various methods of [ProfileBase](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.profile.profilebase.aspx):

```
var profile = ProfileBase.Create(username);
profile.SetPropertyValue("MyGuid", aGuid);
profile.SetPropertyValue("MyString", aString);
// etc
profile.Save()
```